# Jasper Reports - How to create crosstab derived measure?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, crosstab, measure

I need to create a derived column in a jasperreport crosstab e.g.

```
Region   | Type 01 | Type 02 | Derived Measure
zone 1   | Sum     | Sum     | Type 01 / Type 02 ( only in zone 1)
zone 2   | Sum     | Sum     | Type 01 / Type 02 ( only in zone 2)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Rodrigo, do you want this to be performed only by the crosstab element? Or are you open to other ideas?

Comment: I actually got it working using master and detail bands, however as a result I had to write a lot of xml (ireport doesn't work for me). I think this feature can be very usefull, but I couldn't find any clue about how implement it. Do you have another solution in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross tab fills the data at the time of report execution. So it is not possible to find more calculations on already calculated on filled values rather you need to define the Type01/Type02 with in your SQL query so that you can another measure.

Thanks,
Sadakar